# awk to remove lines in file with character in it

Tags: awk

Trying to use `awk` to remove each line that has an`_` in `$5`. The formating of the file makes it look like its `$4`, but neither works. I also tied `sed '/_/d'` but that removed all lines. Thank you :).

**file**

```
chr1    114713907   114713907   chr1:115256528-115256528    NRAS
    chr1    114713789   114713988   NRAS_3
chr1    247424106   247424106   chr1:247587408-247587408    NLRP3
    chr1    247423836   247425609   NLRP3_3
```

**file**

```
chr1    114713907   114713907   chr1:115256528-115256528    NRAS
chr1    247424106   247424106   chr1:247587408-247587408    NLRP3
```

**awk**

```
awk -F\t '$4 !~ /_/'
awk -F\t '$5 !~ /_/'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -F'[[:blank:]]+' '$5!~/_/' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply making `[[:blank:]]` character class as a field separator for all the lines of Input_file. Then checking condition if 5th field is NOT having `_` then print that line(no action mentioned so by default printing of that line will happen).

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Or if its always last field in your Input_file then try following.

```
awk '$NF!~/_/' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `$NF` as that field is last field in every line:

```sh
awk -F '\t' '$NF !~ /_/' file

chr1    114713907   114713907   chr1:115256528-115256528    NRAS
chr1    247424106   247424106   chr1:247587408-247587408    NLRP3
```

Or you can avoid regex:

```sh
awk -F '\t' 'index($NF, "_") == 0' file
```